# Rendering a list in React with some timeout usig setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I am new to react and I was trying to display a list of posts using a json array, and want the list to render afters timeout of certain seconds, but the list is not rendering using the timeout function.

```
render(){
        const posts=[
            { title:"Post One", body:"This is post one"},
            { title:"Post Two", body:"This is post two"}
        ]
        return(
            <>
            <div className={"container"}>
                <h2>{this.state.message}</h2>
                <button className="primary" onClick={this.handleChange}>Change</button>
                <ul>
                <Getpost postDet={posts} />
                </ul>
            </div>
            </>
        )
    }
```

```
export function Getpost(posts){
   // this.setTimeout(()=>{
        //return(

            //console.log("waiting for list to populate")
            return(
                <div>
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    posts.postDet.map((post)=>{
                        return <li key={post.title}>{post.title}</li>;
                    })
                },2000)
                </div>
            )       
            }
```

Can anyone please help me where i am wrong or how can I achieve my task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react if you want to change anything and want that to appear on screen the only way is to render.

The only way you can render is by changing the state.

So the clean answer would be you need to maintain a state with empty values. And on componentdidmount you can have your timeout logic with changing state in it.

Comment: if i will not create a state variable then i can't render it

Comment: could not get what you asked. what is 'it' in your question?

you can create a variable and render it. But if you change the variable in onclick it will not be render changed value. So if you want to change the variable in onclick and you want it to appear then you need to store it in state.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem #1**

Currently, you're trying to get JavaScript code to be executed, but put it inside a JSX `<div>` element, which cannot work (it will just render the code as-is).

This

```
function GetPosts() {
  return (
    <div>
    console.log('hey')
    </div>
  )
}
```

won't print anything at all, it will just display `console.log('hey')` to the user. You can execute code however, by putting it inside curly brackets, like this:

```
function GetPosts() {
  return (
    <div>
    {"hello" + " world"}
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you want to include dynamic data, you can call a function from inside the curly brackets.

**Problem #2**

The `setTimeout` function returns a number that identifies the ongoing timeout (and allows you to clear it before it executes its function), but it returns this number instantly. Showing data after a delay is more complex than that.

You can, for instance, use react hooks which are already a really advanced subject. Here's how it would look:

```
function GetPosts(props) {
  // Create a local state for your posts (and initialize it with an empty array)
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  // Execute setTimeout *only* when the component is created (once)
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => setPosts(props.postDet), 2000);

    // You can optionally (but it's extremely recommended) return another function that will be invoked when the component is unmounted/deleted
    return (() => clearTimout(timeoutID));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map((post)=>{
         return <li key={post.title}>{post.title}</li>;
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

*This is already very complex and you seem to be a begginer in JS, so I highly recommend you to read or learn a bit more before diving in a framework as complex as React. Hope I could help anyways and make myself clear.*

Answer (score 0):

This would work better if you knew more about hooks in **React**. But I assume you don't. So I am giving you a simpler correction below.

Change the code below,

```js
export function Getpost(posts){
   // this.setTimeout(()=>{
        //return(

            //console.log("waiting for list to populate")
            return(
                <div>
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    posts.postDet.map((post)=>{
                        return <li key={post.title}>{post.title}</li>;
                    })
                },2000)
                </div>
            )       
            }
```

to some thing like this

```js
class Getpost extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.setState = {
         hasFinishedLoading : false
      }

      this.setHasFinisedLoading = this.setHasFinisedLoading.bind(this)
   }

  setHasFinisedLoading(event){
     setTimeout(()=>{
        // tell the component that you have finished loading. It will reload the UI automatically
        this.setState({hasFinishedLoading : true});

     },2000)
  }

   render (){
      return(
                <div>
                  {this.state.hasFinishedLoading ? posts.postDet.map((post)=>{
                        return <li key={post.title}>{post.title}</li>;
                    }) : <p></p>
                  }
                </div>
            )  
   }
```

Comment: I would recommend that you read more about React prop to better understand @MrAnima 's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way

```
constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            posts: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        const posts = [
            { title: "Post One", body: "This is post one" },
            { title: "Post Two", body: "This is post two" }
        ]

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ posts: posts })
        }, 2000)
    }

    render(){

        return (
            <>
                <div className={"container"}>
                    <h2>{this.state.message}</h2>
                    <button className="primary" onClick={this.handleChange}>Change</button>
                    <ul>
                        <Getpost postDet={this.state.posts} />
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }




    export function Getpost(posts) {

        return (
            <div>
                posts.postDet&& posts.postDet.length && posts.postDet.map((post)=>{
                            return <li key={post.title}>{post.title}</li>;
            })
                    </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this custom hook  can be much more helpful for you https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useTimeout.md

You need just install `react-use` library

```
import useTimeout from 'react-use/lib/useTimeout';

const PostList = (props) =>{
    const ms = props.ms || 5000;
    const [isReady, cancel] = useTimeout(ms);

    const posts=[
        { title:"Post One", body:"This is post one"},
        { title:"Post Two", body:"This is post two"}
    ]
    return(
        <>
        <div className={"container"}>
            <h2>{this.state.message}</h2>
            <button 
              className="primary" 
              onClick={this.handleChange}                    
             >
                Change
            </button>
            <ul>
              {isReady && <Getpost postDet={posts} />}
            </ul>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```